# "Verifying transaction: failed" Error in updating anaconda form anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, anaconda3, anaconda-cluster

I had been updating anaconda form "anaconda Prompt", i got following error i could not resolve the error can anyone please help me to resolve it

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
libxslt-1.1.33       | 499 KB    | #################################### | 100%
libtiff-4.1.0        | 997 KB    | #################################### | 100%
sqlite-3.31.1        | 961 KB    | #################################### | 100%
krb5-1.17.1          | 846 KB    | #################################### | 100%
libxml2-2.9.9        | 3.5 MB    | #################################### | 100%
bzip2-1.0.8          | 150 KB    | #################################### | 100%
blosc-1.16.3         | 162 KB    | #################################### | 100%
libpng-1.6.37        | 598 KB    | #################################### | 100%
mkl-2020.0           | 156.1 MB  | #################################### | 100%
libcurl-7.68.0       | 284 KB    | #################################### | 100%
intel-openmp-2020.0  | 1.9 MB    | #################################### | 100%
libssh2-1.8.2        | 186 KB    | #################################### | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
```

I have been using anaconda on window 7, 64 bit.

Comment: What command(s) did you run? Is that the entire output/error?

Comment: @AMC  I used "conda update --all" . This is not entire output. After I executed the command I was provided with list  of packages to be updated and asked to proceed by, "Proceed ([y]/n)? ". The output after entering "y" is as above.

Answer (score 3):

This error is about you can not update setuptools in conda env, so you should update conda dependency as fllow 'conda update --update-deps conda' first. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

After trying a number of way, I Could not resolve the issue. Finally, I uninstalled the anaconda, downloaded latest version form the anacondas website and  re-installed it. However, now I have to reinstall all the packages, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following steps:
1- Run Anaconda command prompt as administrator
2-Execute the command: "conda update -n base -c defaults conda"

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the console run on administration mode? If not, verification would be failed due to the file writing authority absence.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).